# How to take input to 2d Dynamic Array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a 2d array using pointers.How do I take input to this 2d array?

```
int **p = new int*[r];
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    p[i] = new int[c];
```

Answer (score 1):

To access any element of 2-D array, imagine it as an array of array. So to access `jth` element in `ith` row, it would be like selecting `jth` element from `p[i]` array. So it would be `p[i][j]`.

Hence, to access any `jth` column (element) in `ith` row, simply use:

```
p[i][j]
```